# Is it possible to run a function that is '2-deep' within another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a function from an `window.onload` event. However the function I want to run lies within another function's function.
I know I can run a function from another function by

```
function1(){
   function2();
}

function2(){
   ...a process...
}
```

But since I cannot run the `window.onload` event within this 'overall' function as it needs to be at the 'top layer'. 
I tried doing this but it didn't work but essentially I think this is what I want to do.

```
<script>
function(){

    function1(){
        ..some stuff..
    }

    function2(){
       function1();
    }
}

window.onload = function2;

</script>
```

I cannot simply run function1 from the `window.onload` event as it is bound by a object onclick event.

Any suggestions to how I can solve this??

Comment: does `function2` have to be inside the outer function, perhaps because it's accessing some private lexically scoped state?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes it does, as the outer function contains a number of functions some of which rely on each other being in the same 'space'. The application is a google geochart, which contains all the options and other things inside this outer function.

Answer (score 0):

You should study and learn the different Javascript patterns that allow you to structure your code in a predictable manner.

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/ is a fantastic resource and will show you the things you need to know.

Each pattern details the implementation, the advantages and the disadvantages.

here's one example that uses the Module pattern:

```
// Global module
var myModule = (function () {

    function privateMethod1() {
       ...
    }

    function privateMethod2() {
      ...
    }

    return {
        publicMethod: function(){
            privateMethod1();
        }
    };

})();

myModule.publicMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility:

```
window.onload = (function(){

    function1(){
        ..some stuff..
    }

    function2(){
       function1();
    }

    return function2;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you invoke the outer function yourself, there's no reason that the assignment to `window.onload` cannot happen *within* that:

```
(function(){

    function1() {
        ..some stuff..
    }

    function2() {
       function1();
    }

    window.onload = function2;

})();  // immediately invoked function expression
```